# R split DF and run tests in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have two matrices that I want to do several statistics, where I compare every row of dataframe1 with dataframe2. These are large data frame (300,000 rows and 40,000 rows) so lots to compare.

I made a few functions to be apply the statistics. What I was wondering was whether it is possible to split dataframe1 into chunks are run these chunks in parallel on multiple cores.

```
library(lawstat)
library(reshape2)
df1 = matrix(ncol= 100, nrow=100)
for ( i in 1:100){
  df1[,i] =floor(runif(100, min = 0, max =3))
}

df2 = matrix(ncol= 100, nrow=1000)
for ( i in 1:100){
  df2[,i] =runif(1000, min = 0, max =1000)
}

testFunc<- function(df1, df2){
      x=apply(df1, 1, function(x) apply(df2, 1, function(y) levene.test(y,x)$p.value))
      x=melt(x)
      return(x)
    }

system.time(res <- testFunc(df1,df2 ))
```

Some of the statistics (e.g. levene tests) take a fairly long time to compute so any ways I can speed this up would be great.

Comment: I don't have time to write or test a specific solution, but this can certainly be accomplished using the `parallel` package. `library(parallel);  ?parRapply`

Comment: Can your dataframe be coerced to a matrix? (Is there only numeric data in it?)

Comment: Yes it is all numeric data and can be in a matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is room for optimisation in your function but here is an example of an improvement using the `parallel` package:

```
library(parallel)
library(snow)

# I have a quad core processor so I am using 3 cores here.
cl <- snow::makeCluster(3)
testFunc2<- function(df1, df2){
  x <- parallel::parApply(cl = cl, X = df1, 1, function(x, df2) apply(df2, 1, 
function(y) lawstat::levene.test(y,x)$p.value), df2)
  x <- melt(x)
  return(x)
}
system.time(res <- testFunc2(df1,df2 ))
```

On my machine this at least halves the running time if I have a cluster size of 3.

edit: I felt bad for dissing your code so below is a stripped down levene.test function that increases performance more that going parallel on most home/work machines.

```
lev_lite <- function(y, group){
  N <- 100 # or length(y)
  k <- 3   # or length(levels(group)) after setting to as.factor below
  
  reorder <- order(group)
  group <- group[reorder]
  y <- y[reorder]
  group <- as.factor(group)
  n <- tapply(y,group, FUN = length)
  yi_bar <- tapply(y,group, FUN = median)
  zij <- abs(y - rep(yi_bar, n))
  zidot <- tapply(zij, group, FUN = mean)
  zdotdot <- mean(zij)
  # test stat, see wiki
  W <- ((N - k)/(k - 1)) * (
    sum(n*(zidot - zdotdot)^2)/
      sum((zij - rep(zidot, n))^2))
  
  #p val returned
  1 - pf(W, k-1, N-k)
}

testFunc2 <- function(df1, df2){
  x <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) apply(df2, 1, lev_lite, group = x))
  x <- melt(x)
  return(x)
}

> system.time(res <- testFunc(df1[1:50, ],df2[1:50,] ))
user  system elapsed 
5.53    0.00    5.56 
> system.time(res2 <- testFunc2(df1[1:50, ],df2[1:50, ] ))
user  system elapsed 
1.13    0.00    1.14 
> max(res2 - res)
[1] 2.220446e-15
```

This is a ~5x improvement without parallelisation.

Comment: Brilliant, I'm curious what optimisation you were thinking?
Your answer is what I was after though!

Comment: I guess it depends on if you will be running this analysis regularly, but if you are running a simulation or using a very clean dataset it can be good to make a stripped down version of a built in function. I have edit my comment to include an example. I used the source/wikipedia to write `lev_lite` (see my edit).

Comment: Ah, I see. Once I know the exact test I will run then I will have a go and implementing a lite version as you have done above.